# Nativescript OCR fails with generic error

Tags: ocr, nativescript

I am trying to use the [nativescript-ocr](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-ocr) plugin, and keep on getting this error message

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/newcard/newcard.component.js:133:34: {
  "error": "Recognize failed, check the log for possible details."
}
```

It is very unhelpful, and i have been stuck on it for too long.

Bellow you can see how i am implementing the ocr:

```
doRecognize(source: string): void {
console.log({source});
let img: ImageSource = new ImageSource()
img.fromResource(source).then((success: boolean) => {
  if (success) {
    this.ocr.retrieveText({
      image: img,
      language: 'eng',
      onProgress: (percentage: number ) => {
        console.log(`Decoding progress: ${percentage}%`);
      }
    }).then(
        (result: RetrieveTextResult) => {
          console.log(`Result: ${result.text}`);
        },
          (error) => {
        })
     }
  });
}
```

The source string looks like so:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/newcard/newcard.component.js:122:20: {
"source": 
"file:///Users/georgekyr/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0723299A-7C8B-40C3-AE74- FEE8E08BB52D/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0007.PNG" 
}
```

Looking around, I find that there are cases wehere the folder `app/tesseract/tessadata` was created in the wrong way, so i have double checked that the folder exists in the right place with the right data in it.

Comment: Have you tried the Firebase plugin with MLKit, as indicated at the top of that (deprecated) repo?

Comment: I am not using Firebase at all (which might not be such a great idea), so i wanted to see if i can go around it. I would have to create a firebase project just for a small part of my app. However, If there is no other way to fix my current issue, i guess I will have go for the Firebase implementation.

Comment: It's easier to set up than you might think... and only the relevant native libraries are included in your app by nativescript-plugin-firebase; if you don't need the realtime database features for instance, then the Pod / .aar isn't added to your project.

Comment: I tried the demo-ng app from your plugin, and i is indeed very good and easy to use. I will switch to that instead. Thanks for your work @EddyVerbruggen